# AWS CloudFront: Origin and Alternate Domain Name = same domain name

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I have an online store that is accessible at **[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)**. Now I want to add **[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)** as origin to CloudFront but I also want to use **[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)** as the alternate domain name under which the store should still be reachable. Is this possible at all?

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: No. Adding subdomain as origin makes no sense.